# violates foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, go

I keep receiving this error:
insert or update on table "note" violates foreign key constraint "note_username_fkey"

I have two tables: User and Note. Here are the create table statements:

```
func setup() *sql.DB {
db = connectDatabase()
//Create queries
userTable := `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "User"(
    UserID SERIAL unique,
    UserName VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Password VARCHAR(40)
    );`

noteTable := `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Note(
    NoteID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID INT,
    UserName VARCHAR(50),
    Title VARCHAR(30),
    Contents VARCHAR(1000),
    DateCreated DATE,
    DateUpdated DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserName) REFERENCES "User"(UserName)
    );`
```

}

```
    func createNoteInsertSQL(userID string, userName string, title string, content string, selectSetting string) bool {
var newNote Note
var err error

newNote.UserID, err = strconv.Atoi(userID)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
newNote.UserName = userName
newNote.Title = title
newNote.Contents = content
date := time.Now()
newNote.DateCreated = date
newNote.DateUpdated = date

query := `INSERT INTO Note (UserID, UserName, Title, Contents, DateCreated, DateUpdated) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING NoteID;`
stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return false
}

var noteID int
err = stmt.QueryRow(newNote.UserID, newNote.UserName, newNote.Title, newNote.Contents, newNote.DateCreated, newNote.DateUpdated).Scan(&noteID)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return false
}
```

}

Can anyone please tell me where the wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create user first for foreign key constraints or send null in username of note table column.

Comment: Have you read up on what [foreign keys in relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) are?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether "Username" column value you try to insert in note table is already available in "User" table. Because the insert query is trying to insert value that is not available in "User" table.